# Turn on/off location when doing UI Tests Android

Tags: android, android-testing, android-location, ui-testing

I'm trying to turn on or off the location of the device depending on what I want to test.

I've already looked into [Test-Butler](https://github.com/linkedin/test-butler) but turns out that I can't use it because of this:

> Test Butler helper app requires an emulator image with stock Android else it won't install, therefore it will not work with non-stock emulator images such as ones with Google APIs or Google Play! and

And **I'm implementing Google Maps in my app** and so on Google API and google play are on my device so this looks like it leads to an error crash and isn't a solution for my case.

**Question:** What should I look into for turning on or off before a test?

Comment: https://droidbyme.medium.com/android-turn-on-gps-programmatically-d585cf29c1ef

Comment: Sadly, that's what I'm not looking for. Since it requires me to be aware if location is enabled or not when entering into a test and then add Espresso clicks to be enable gps when location is off or worse it will throw an error because couldn't find the the click and will stop the test if location is on. So is there some framework/library that could help me by enabling this before entering into a test? @HB.

Comment: `So is there some framework/library that could help me by enabling this before entering into a test?` You will have to check if location is enabled and only enable it when it's not. Then you can run the "test".

Comment: Ah yeah got it. My bad then I kinda expected to be more easy, thanks for the solution, if you want to answer the question and I give you the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check if location is enabled and only enable it when it's not.

You can check if location is enabled like this:

```java
public boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) { 
    int locationMode = 0; 
    String locationProviders;
    try { 
        locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE); 
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return false; 
    } 
    return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF; 
}
```

If the above returns `false` then you can [enable](https://droidbyme.medium.com/android-turn-on-gps-programmatically-d585cf29c1ef) it. Then do your "test".